# Singleton resource - how to delete a different resource than the singleton

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, resources

In routes.rb I have

`map.resource :user`

In one of my templates I want to

`link_to 'delete', some_other_user`, :method => :post

I was hoping this would generate a url like

`/user/#{some_other_user.id}`

but instead get

`/user.#{user.to_s}`

The only solution I've found is to add a new route

`map.delete_user 'users/:id', :controller => 'users', :action => 'destroy', :method => :delete`

and then use

`link_to 'delete', delete_user_url(user), :method => :delete`

This seems a bit hacky, is there a cleaner way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A singleton resource would normally be used to perform operations on one resource, for example, the current user.  If I wanted to manipulate another user, for example from an administrator's perspective, I would

```
  map.resources :users
```

If I only wanted to perform the destroy operation on other users I would

```
  map.resources :users, :only => [:destroy]
```

Then you would only be able to perform the destroy action.

In this user editing their account and administrator administrating all accounts situation (if I'm assuming correctly) I would create two controllers,

- AccountsController - allow the current user to edit their account (singleton resource)
- UsersController - allow administrators to edit all user accounts

Routes would be like so:

```
  map.resource :account
  map.resources :users
```

In this way permissions can be separated into normal user and administrator permissions, if required.

Hope this helps

Comment: My first attempt was to use 

   map.resource :user and 
   map.resource :users, :only => [:destroy]

mapped to the same controller. I didn't think of using separate controllers though, that looks like the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to AntRamm's answer, to get a destroy URL for resources you need to manually specify the method as delete:

```
link_to 'delete', user_url(some_other_user), :method => :delete
```

See `the docs` for more info.